# Dealing with Firestore Database object

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I overcome my latest issue with help of Alex Mamo regarding this [video]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s

But I had a problem again, now. I added my specific collection into artifactInformatics array which contains Integer cause in database I have collection of object which they had 3 different number fields. So when I add specific object into artifactInformatics array, I want to get those 3 fields that contains number into different three variables in my project in order to use them. So here is the code:

```
readData(new FirestoneCallBack() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCallBack(List<Integer> artifactInformatics) {
                                Integer array = artifactInformatics.get(0);
                            }
                        });

private void readData(final FirestoneCallBack firestoneCallBack){
        int index = Integer.parseInt(inputString) - 1;
        Task<QuerySnapshot> documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("mapLocations")
                .whereEqualTo("artifactID",index)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        List<Integer> artifactInformatics = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())){
                                int currentArtifact = document.toObject(Integer.class);
                                artifactInformatics.add(currentArtifact);
                            }
                            firestoneCallBack.onCallBack(artifactInformatics);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private interface FirestoneCallBack {
        void onCallBack(List<Integer> artifactInformatics);
    }
```

Here is quick screenshot of example object that I am trying to get: 
[image: Example screenshot of my object that has three number fields.]

Comment: There are 3 values why you used only Integer.class on `document`?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @Ashish what you mean by that ? I did not get it

Comment: @AlexMamo for example: I want to reach document "0" and their three fields in order to use those fields in my project.

Comment: @AlexMamo I couldn't figure out where i should get those field and how ? Can you tell me the process flow in your video one by one? I mean what is the order of the program is reading in code?

Comment: What do you mean through "use those fields in my project"? Are you able to at least log them?

Comment: @AlexMamo no sadly i can not able to log them out. I tried but I dont know where to access them. I did whatever you did on your video about Asynchronous API. I couldn't figured out program flow over the video and where should I try to access those fields.